# Is it possible to calculate the size of a file created from a base64 string only?

Tags: base64

Is it possible to calculate the size of a file created from a base64 string? The file type varies. I know it can't be exact but an approximate size would be enough.

I have only been provided the base64 string.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> the size of the decoded data can be approximated with this formula:

```
bytes = (string_length(encoded_string) - 814) / 1.37
```

Comment: Thanks, it got me a size close enough. I had a base64 string (actually an mp4 video) with a length of 442693.

Using this calculation, the size is (442693 - 814) / 1.37 = 322539.4160583942, when saved as a .mp4 file the size is 332019 bytes.

Comment: Like it says, it's just an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

```
base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64......";

var stringLength = base64String.length - 'data:image/png;base64,'.length;

var sizeInBytes = 3 * Math.ceil((stringLength / 4));
var sizeInKb=sizeInBytes/1000;
```

Comment: Removed the quotes